# Google services ; com.google.gms:google-services:2.1.2 ; failed to resolve services-measurement

Tags: android-studio, gradle, google-play-services

Just trying to update to the latest google play services 9.4.0. If I leave the classpath in the application level gradle to 2.1.2 which seems to be the latest release as of June 03, [link](https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/#release), I get the error failed to resolve :

Error:Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:9.4.0
Install Repository and sync project

I have already my packages updated in SDK manager.
If I leave the classpath as 3.0.0 which was the release of May things seem to be ok. Any idea as to why I get such error with the 2.1.2 version classpath? see below for my gradle files. Android Studio version : 2.1.3. Appreciate any help.

build.gradle Project Level:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.1.2'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.gradle app Level:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.main.projectone"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'


    compile('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.0') {
        exclude module: 'bolts-android'
    }

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'

    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.13.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:okhttp3-integration:1.4.0@aar'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.8.1'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.firebase:geofire-android:2.0.0'

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.4.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using the version **9.4.0** you have to use the google play service plugin v 3.0.0:

```
buildscript {
    // ...
    dependencies {
        // ...
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}
```

Check the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) for the setup.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Gabriele, I agree; the firebase documentation mentions google-services:3.0.0. I am wondering why things don't work with the release of June 03, i.e, version 2.1.2 which I presume its the most recent release. Either way I am going forward with 3.0.0 for now at least.